# How to use a int/double in and out of a loop for Java

Tags: java, loops, percentage

```
public class TaxesV2Wendt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        final double TAX = .1;
        final double TAX1 = .15;
        final double TAX2 = .25;
        final double TAX3 = .28;
        final double TAX4 = .33;
        final double TAX5 = .35;
        final double TAX6 = .396;

        final int INCOME = 9075;
        final int INCOME1 = 36900;
        final int INCOME2 = 89350;
        final int INCOME3 = 186350;
        final int INCOME4 = 405100;
        final int INCOME5 = 406750;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Enter your yearly income");
            double year_Income = in.nextDouble();
            double all = 0;
            if (year_Income <= 9074) {
                System.out.println("Your tax is 10%");
                double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX);
                System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
                all = +taxes;
            } else if (year_Income >= INCOME && year_Income <= INCOME1) {
                System.out.println("Your tax is 15%");
                double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX1);
                System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
                all = +taxes;
            } else if (year_Income >= INCOME1 && year_Income <= INCOME2) {
                System.out.println("Your tax is 25%");
                double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX2);
                System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
                all = +taxes;
            } else if (year_Income >= INCOME2 && year_Income <= INCOME3) {
                System.out.println("Your tax is 28%");
                double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX3);
                System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
                all = +taxes;
            } else if (year_Income >= INCOME3 && year_Income <= INCOME4) {
                System.out.println("Your tax is 33%");
                double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX4);
                System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
                all = +taxes;
            } else if (year_Income >= INCOME4 && year_Income <= INCOME5) {
                System.out.println("Your tax is 35%");
                double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX5);
                System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
                all = +taxes;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Your tax is 39.6");
                double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX6);
                System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
                all = +taxes;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total Taxes");
        System.out.println(all);
    }
}
```

Having trouble please help. need to print result of the all variable but it wont find the variable........  Trying to do taxes and its so much easier to do this lol. also if possible are my taxes right so far????So confused thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `all` variable out of the loop. so that you can use this variable in print statement.

In your case modified code would be :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    final double TAX = .1;
    final double TAX1 = .15;
    final double TAX2 = .25;
    final double TAX3 = .28;
    final double TAX4 = .33;
    final double TAX5 = .35;
    final double TAX6 = .396;

    final int INCOME = 9075;
    final int INCOME1 = 36900;
    final int INCOME2 = 89350;
    final int INCOME3 = 186350;
    final int INCOME4 = 405100;
    final int INCOME5 = 406750;

    double all = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Enter your yearly income");
        double year_Income = in.nextDouble();

        if (year_Income <= 9074) {
            System.out.println("Your tax is 10%");
            double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX);
            System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
            all += taxes;
        } else if (year_Income >= INCOME && year_Income <= INCOME1) {
            System.out.println("Your tax is 15%");
            double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX1);
            System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
            all += taxes;
        } else if (year_Income >= INCOME1 && year_Income <= INCOME2) {
            System.out.println("Your tax is 25%");
            double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX2);
            System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
            all += taxes;
        } else if (year_Income >= INCOME2 && year_Income <= INCOME3) {
            System.out.println("Your tax is 28%");
            double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX3);
            System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
            all += taxes;
        } else if (year_Income >= INCOME3 && year_Income <= INCOME4) {
            System.out.println("Your tax is 33%");
            double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX4);
            System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
            all += taxes;
        } else if (year_Income >= INCOME4 && year_Income <= INCOME5) {
            System.out.println("Your tax is 35%");
            double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX5);
            System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
            all += taxes;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your tax is 39.6");
            double taxes = ((double) year_Income * TAX6);
            System.out.println("You Owe" + taxes);
            all += taxes;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total Taxes : "+all);

    in.close();
}
```

Comment: I have also added `in.close();` to avoid any memory leak.

Comment: Only thing is now it doesnt add up for the 5 inputs.

Comment: 100 is outputed 5 times which should add to 500 but not sure where to go there

Comment: now it will do , updated code to `all += taxes;` 
previously you were using `all = +taxes` which will not add data to variable, you have to use `all += taxes;`  to add.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks so much! Stand by i might have another question coming up lol.

Answer (score 2):

You `all` variable is a block variable. It can't be seen outside of the if/else blocks.
If you want to access it outside the block(but inside the for loop) you have to move the declaration of `all` variable to the scope of for loop

e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    double all = 0.0;
    ..
```

But based on your logic i think u have to define it outside the for loop. (Because you are adding value to existing value of `all`)

So it can be

```
double all = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        ..
```

Comment: }
   
  }
  System.out.println("Total Taxes");
  System.out.println(all);

Comment: There you go sory took long bc the 4 space thing

Comment: You are trying to print the value of variable all outside the for loop. But you have declared it inside the for loop. You must declare that before the for loop

Comment: So like if i did 1000, 5 times it only does 100 instead of 500

Comment: all += ... should get executed the every time for loop get executed

Answer (score 1):

You are defining **all** inside braces. As soon as your braces ends, scope of **all** ends. so your compiler will not be able to find ***all***.
you will have to define **all** outside of for loop. if you define it inside loop then also it will be overwritten every time loop starts.

Comment: Define all outside for loop. Also, i don't see the end of your for loop. put one "}" before your **System.out.println(all);** statement.

Comment: use `backtick` (the key below tilde above tab, on the left of key number 1) to put format as code, do not make it bold like that

Comment: @ Lưu Vĩnh Phúc Thanks for suggestion. I will take care next time.